# Carrier model furnace inducer motor turns on and off briefly

Tags: air-conditioning

I have a carrier model furnace where the inducer motor will turn on for approximately 10 seconds then shut off for a minute or so.  It only recently started doing this and it only does it my thermostat is set at 74 or higher.  Any time I have the thermostat set at 70 or 72 it runs normal. Any help would be appreciated.  Thank you!

Comment: What's the model number on your furnace?

Answer (score 0):

The fact that it sometimes works correctly eliminates most of the possible issues, such as a bad pressure sensor or duct blockage. So the fact that it ONLY happens at a specific temperature setting means it has something to do with the overall system operation.

My guess would be that the furnace is beginning its start cycle, which means the inducer comes on, then MAYBE the air moving through the inducer is enough to trigger the thermostat to stop calling for the furnace before the start cycle is complete and the burners come on. Every thermostat has a "hysteresis", a dead band between when it calls for the heat and when it stops. Without that the heater would cycle on and off too much. So for example when you set the t-stat for 74, it will really turn ON at 72, then turn OFF at 76, averaging out at 74 (which is also affected by how the air mixes in the space). In your case either that hysteresis is off kilter, or the mere fact of the inducer air flow coming on is changing the t-stat sensing to below that point. That may be the result of your t-stat being too close to the air intake of the furnace so that the draft created by the inducer is cooling your t-stat. or it could just be a bad component somewhere.